# Can a particular file be downloaded from s3 bucket using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3

I am trying to extract only particular files from an s3 bucket. Currently I am able to display the contents of the bucket. Can anyone guide me on how to extract a particular file? I am using javascript and jquery.

Comment: this might help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799956/javascript-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3-bucket

Comment: Thanks. Got my answer.