# AWS S3 File Download from the client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently trying to download the file from the s3 bucket using a button from the front-end. How is it possible to do this? I don't have any idea on how to start this thing. I have tried researching and researching, but no luck -- all I have searched are about **UPLOADING** files to the s3 bucket but not **DOWNLOADING** files. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I am applying it to **ReactJS (Frontend)** and **NodeJS (Backend)** and also, the file is uploaded using Webmerge

**UPDATE: I am trying to generate a download link with this** (Tried node even if I'm not a backend dev) (lol)

**see images below**

[what I have tried so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuVXU.png)

[onClick function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqbhe.png)

Comment: What did you try ? Simple search gives me this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: It's normally just an HTTP GET (i.e. a standard web download) I think, with the right credentials attached if it's a non-public bucket.

Comment: @Rup, Oh I see, can't find that **right credentials** tho

Comment: you can use anchor tag with the link to that file. And please explain your answer so that others can understand what you trying to do and what you have done yet.

Comment: I have update my question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Apolozeus I have updated my question and supported it with images of codes. Thanks :)

Comment: @RohitDhiman I have updated my question and supported it with images of codes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the file you are trying to download is not public then you have to create a signed url to get that file.

The solution is here [Javascript to download a file from amazon s3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799956/javascript-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3-bucket)
 for getting non public files, which revolves around creating a lambda function that will generate a signed url for you then use that url to download the file on button click

BUT if the file you are trying to download you is public then you don't need a signed url, you just need to know the path to the file, the urls are structured like: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ [file path]/[filename]

They is also aws amplify its created and maintain by AWS team.

Just follow [Get started](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/react_guide) and downloading the file from your react app is simply as:

```
Storage.get('hello.png', {expires: 60})
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Great! Thanks :)

Comment: Please do let me know how it goes and if my answer was any of help towards you I would I appreciated if I got an upvote or marked as the correct answer :)

Comment: It isn't as easy as logging to the console, because logging to the console is not getting the file downloaded to my users. I can't find any examples of how to actually get the link onto the page or downloaded to the user. It is a promise, so I have to wait on it, and can't just add it to a link tag...

Answer (score 13):

Here is my solution:

```
let downloadImage = url => {
  let urlArray = url.split("/")
  let bucket = urlArray[3]
  let key = `${urlArray[4]}/${urlArray[5]}`
  let s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: bucket }})
  let params = {Bucket: bucket, Key: key}
  s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    let blob=new Blob([data.Body], {type: data.ContentType});
    let link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download=url;
    link.click();
  })
}
```

The url in the argument refers to the url of the S3 file.

Just put this in the `onClick` method of your button. You will also need the `AWS SDK`

Comment: can u add the html part of this solution

Comment: @Banani720 <button onClick=(() => downloadImage(url))>Click me</button>

Comment: I would think there should be a cleanup step to revoke the object URL and remove the link from the DOM.