# How to download a file from S3 bucket directly to the browser using AWS SDK (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-sdk

I am using Aws S3 resource object of AWS SDK in my Rails code to download a file from my S3 bucket this way:

```rb
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')
  obj = s3.bucket('mybucket').object( my_report_file_name)
  obj.get(response_target: my_report_file_name)
```

The `get` method in the last line shown above downloads the file from S3 bucket to the Rails server machine. I would like to download the file to the client browser directly instead.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you have to use javascript for that using localstorage. But others maybe able to give better solution.

Comment: Already answered in the below link for Nodejs. May be you have to write code for Ruby on Rails https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799956/javascript-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3-bucket

Comment: @m.beginner did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the object, and you want to download it through the browser into the user's file directory, you might be looking for [send_data](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data):

`send_data(obj, filename: 'my_report_file_name')`