# cannot download image from URL react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

in my react app i am trying to download an image from an S3 URL using following code.

```
<a href={ele.payment_receipt} download target="_blank" class="text-link-3 fw-3 ">
                        <i class="icon-download mr-2"></i>Download</a>
```

where ele.payment_receipt is the link of file. but when i click on the link it opens it new tab instead of downloading it. I have tried online solutions but all online solutions tell the same method to download  can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here? thanks in advance

**EDIT**
URL of the image is the SignedUrl of an s3 bucket image which expires after 60 seconds.

Comment: try removing `target="_blank"`

Comment: @HardikChaudhary now it's opening the image in same tab instead of new tab

Comment: working example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

Comment: @HardikChaudhary that example wont work for different origin urls [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

Answer (score 3):

For your information, Firefox and Chrome 65+ only support same-origin download links, probably as a security measure.

The Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG) also recommends that the web server that is hosting the image/file in question needs to send a Content-Disposition HTTP header for download= to be honored.

In short:

You can only use  to force download of an image/file, if:

the server that hosts the image/file also says it should be downloaded,
or
the image/file comes from the same domain.

Please check whether from the server Content-Disposition header is coming from the server or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can take help from the below article:
https://www.roytuts.com/download-file-from-server-using-react/

But again if the request is made to other domains then the CORS problem will come and this needs to be handled separately from the server-side to support CORS.

Comment: i have used this  answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50405118/8196136. i have django backend which gives signedurls for s3 objects and i am using that url to download it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `download` attribute to download files which are in different URL(cross-origin) for more information you can [refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

Instead what you can do is, make an API call, convert it to blob and download it. You can refer this how to do that [gist](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743)  and [working-codesandbox-sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/download-cross-origin-image-ksitw).

Answer (score 0):

A simple component to download data from a client-side cache (e.g. flux, redux).

Design to be used with browserify or webpack.

Install with:

`npm i react-download-link`

```
import DownloadLink from "react-download-link";

<DownloadLink
    label="Save"
    filename="myfile.txt"
    exportFile={() => "My cached data"}
/>
```