# How do I use Node.js to read server file within a Django application?

Tags: node.js, django, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a django application that I use to visualize data. The data itself is in an Amazon S3 bucket, and the plotting of the data is done using bokeh. One of the applications however, uses `d3` instead. And while I managed to configure the bokeh apps to work properly, I don't know how to do that with the d3 app. It has to read data either directly from S3 or locally (If I download it within django views before rendering the web page) and plot it. But whatever I try I get a 404 Not Found error.

I'm learning as I go, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Going through SO, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799956/javascript-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3-bucket) which gives an example of downloading a file from S3 using Node.js, but I am already running a django server so I don't know if that works. I should also mention that the files to be read are quite large (several megabytes). So, to summarize, my question is:

Is using Node.js my only solution here and can it be done without having both Nodejs and django running at the same time? I'm worried that this might be too complex for me to set up. Or better yet, what would be a recommended solution in my case? I am almost done with the whole project but, unfortunately, I've gotten stuck pretty bad here.

Thank you to anyone willing to help or offer advice.

Comment: You can use `boto` if you want to stay with python/django, create a view that downloads and returns the file https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html

Comment: Thank you. I am already using ```boto``` for the rest of the project, but I guess I don't know how far I can stretch its usage. The javascript applications have to read and reload separate data based on user actions so I don't know if using ```boto``` is the right idea. I also wouldn't mind using Node.js if it gets the job done, I'm only worried using both Node and Django might be very difficult/complex.