# S3 image link getting downloaded for some image links and viewed for some image links

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm trying to select files from my system and uploading it in the AWS S3 Bucket. When trying to do so, the URL that is generated gets downloaded when clicked but when I upload it from the camera and not selecting it from the system, I'm getting the URL which can be viewed from the browser.

I got to know that the links are stored in **virtual host style** when uploaded from the camera and stored in **path style** when selected from the file system. How can I make the S3 URL's downloadable either way ?

Comment: Can you give us the example?

Comment: I think that you need to pass `ACL: 'public-read'` and `ContentType: 'image/jpeg'` in your s3 params

Comment: If I'll give `ContentType: 'image/jpeg'` it'll make it viewable in the browser. I was looking for a way to make it downloadable.

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799956/javascript-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3-bucket